# url rewriting not working htaccess with show.php?id=12321

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My htaccess url rewriting is not working below is code of my htaccess file, my url is

```
domain/show.php?id=12312
```

I want to show it as domain/show/12321

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^show/([0-9]+)/?$    show.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: How is it now working? Don't you see the correct page when you try to open `domain/show/12321`? Note that there is a difference between rewriting and redirecting.

Comment: it is showing /show.php?id=12321 i want to show it as /show/12321  domain is djpal.co u can check it there

Comment: Instead of writing in the if module, try testing it by writing it outside the if module and see if it will work, if it does then figure out why your if module isn't working in the .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Please  try this:

```
 //301 Redirect Old File
Redirect 301 http://djpal.co/show.php?id=1585633 http://djpal.co/show.php/1585633
```

Comment: please add this 

//301 Redirect Old File
Redirect 301 http://djpal.co/show.php?id=1585633 http://djpal.co/show.php/1585633

Comment: this is not one url sir, there are dynamic urls with different ids, i need to rewrite not redirect thnku, u can check online domain djpal.co

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to rewrite, please clear if not.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^show/([0-9]+)/?$ show.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Now when you try url domain.com/show/12321 in browser it will rewritten to actual url.

Comment: it is not working sir, do i need to write anything on show.php file ? you can check online djpal.co/show.php?id=1585634

Comment: Okay where did you used the htaccess file?

Comment: i used htaccess in domain main directory

Answer (score 0):

//let's try to this, and you get the $_REQUEST["id"] value.

RewriteRule ^show/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) show.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

Comment: domain/show.php?id=1585634 my url is this type and if i will use http://djpal.co/show/1585634 this url then how can i read last integers from url in show.php page to fetch data from msyql